# Invoking a self parameter in a self function when self is weak inside a escaping closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures

Good evening.

I come bearing a doubt about escaping (asynchronous) closures in Swift, and I'd want to know which would be the best way to solve it.

There's an example function.

```swift
func exampleFunction() {
   functionWithEscapingClosure(onSuccess: { result in
      self.anotherFunction(parameter: self.parameter, result: result)
   }
}
```

As you've probably noticed, this will cause a memory leak, since onSuccess is an escaping closure and it's retaining self.

Now, the way to solve it is adding [weak self] in the closure. And I want anotherFunction to be invoked only if self isn't nil, so it would be like that:

```swift
func exampleFunction() {
   functionWithEscapingClosure(onSuccess: { [weak self] result in
      self?.anotherFunction(parameter: self.parameter, result: result)
   }
}
```

But the parameter is an issue, since I can't pass on a nil parameter, I have to unwrap self to use the parameter.

Would it be safe to use a force unwrap (`self!.parameter`), since the function only gets called if self is not nil?
Should I perform a variable binding for `self?.parameter` before calling `self?.anotherFunction`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write

```
self?.anotherFunction(parameter: self!.parameter, result: result)
```

If `self` is `nil` the function isn't called at all.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use this after your capture list

```
guard let `self` = self else { return }
```

Your function should be like this:

```
func exampleFunction() {
   functionWithEscapingClosure(onSuccess: { [weak self] result in
      guard let `self` = self else { return }
      self.anotherFunction(parameter: self.parameter, result: result)
   }
}
```

So, dont worry about the optional (?) anymore.

Comment: You don't have to use the backticks anymore, guard let self = self else { return } will work also

Comment: Yes i know, but my answer was edited several mins ago by admin (may be) and the `` were added